# Can not be inherited with different types arguments

Tags: java, generics

Suppose you have `EntityService<E>`, `PersonService extends EntityService<Person>`, `EmployeeService extends EntityService<Employee>` and so on. Now suppose you want to create one `SuperService` aggregating other services, which would be exposed to outer world. Due of generics erasure, you can not write `SuperService extends PersonService, EmployeeService`, ... Is there any way how to solve this without writing specific method names for each service?

```
public interface EntityService<E> {
    E find(long id);
    ...
}

public interface PersonService extends EntityService<Person> { }
public interface EmployeeService extends EntityService<Employee> { } 

// ERROR - SuperService can not be inherited with different types arguments
public interface SuperService extends PersonService, EmployeeService {}
```

Currently I'm writting specific methods in `SuperInterface` which are delegated  to underlying services. I'm curious, whether there is some annotation processor that is able to generate working service interface with minimal effort.

Comment: That's not why you can't do that. You can't do that because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you want it to look like when somebody uses `SuperService`?

Comment: AFAIK, java does not support multiple inheritance in classes, so could you please clarify what you mean by `SuperService extends PersonService, EmployeeService`?

Comment: @mypetlion He didn't explicitly say `PersonService` must be a class. If those types were interfaces, he'd still have the same issue as he mentions in his post.

Comment: @VinceEmigh true, but at the same time it's deduced from the context: `PersonService implements EntityService<Person>`. That is why I asked for clarifications

Comment: @Morfic sorry, I did not notice I have written implements, I wanted to write extends casue this is all about interfaces.

Comment: @VinceEmigh correct again, I'm simply trying to get the facts straight before anything. Sorry if I seem overzealous, but I had a few cases where _the problem wasn't the problem_ if you know what I mean. Matoni, it sounds  to me like you want to create an object with multiple responsabilities. Can you please elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @Morfic Yes, the XY problem, very common. Asking for clarification is always the best route. Wasn't downing, rather it seemed many people were (rightfully) confused about what he was asking about. Matoni: You need different method names, as you can't overload via only a return type.

Comment: @Morfic I know such a design is breaking SRP principle - not result of my work. I'm just trying to refactor this class without breaking functionality. Splitting API would require refactoting of multiple projects which is what I want to avoid, so I want to separate services only at implemenation level (hidden by "SuperInterface").

Comment: @matoni Even if there were *no* interfaces, you cannot create overloads which differ only in return types. This isn't a problem of inheritance, or even erasure. You're trying to define overloads that only differ in their return type, and that's not possible. You *need* to have separate method identifiers or parameters. [Overloads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) must have different [method signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), and the return type is not part of a method's signature.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm aware of this limitations, I'm just wondering, if there is some annotation processor like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all) to overcome these difficulties.

Comment: Sorry, it's sill unclear to me what exactly you are trying to refactor/achieve. What do you mean by _'this class'_? Do you now have the `SuperInterface` (or some sort of implementation) and you' re trying to _split_ it into tinier pieces, or something else?

Comment: @Morfic originaly, `SuperInterface` and it's implementation had all services methods at one place. I have separate them in standalone services for easier maintenance but still, I need to expose them under `SuperInterface` to not to break it's contract on which relies several projects.

Comment: Well then you already have the contract that should not change, in the form of `SuperInterface`. If my understanding is correct and you'll just be using **IT** to avoid major refactoring within multiple modules,  I see no reason to force it to extend 2 smaller interfaces since you're not going to use them at all. You can just go for composition and delegate the initial calls to each separate smaller service implementation. Finally, you can work with these 2 delegate interfaces in the _'SuperImplementation'_, if you believe it makes sense to have another abstraction layer. @VinceEmigh thoughts?

Comment: @Morfic Composition was what I was thinking aswell. In fact, I see no reason for the client to need to know of the actual services (which they would if he kept trying to solve this via inheritance). See my answer

Comment: @Morfic That's exactly what I'm doing right now, but it's pain to delegate all the methods to multiple interfaces.

Comment: See my comment to @VinceEmigh reply. Perhaps that can be a different option. It's 03:31 here so I really need to get some sleep, but I may be able to provide a sample tomorrow on which we can improve (maybe my explanation is not clear enough atm, although that will not actually allow you to refactor the current class, but more like expose fewer methods to your new clients untill you decide to migrate everything, if at all possible)

Comment: Alternatively, to make it less of a pain (maybe), adjust the solution suggested by @VinceEmigh. Inject a (let's call it) _`ServiceCache`_ in your `SuperImplementation`, and call the appropriate method with the desired entity type, which should be known at that time. This way the contract does not change at all, and you can benefit from his solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're implying you want a single-entry point for this API, hence your `SuperService`. If so, and if you don't mind casting:

1. Store the services in a `Map`
2. Require the client to specify what they want to access.

This allows easy storing of the services, as well as a simple way to access the entity that the client wants.

```
class SuperService {
    private Map<Class<?>, EntityService<?>> services = ...;

    public SuperService() { //populate the map somehow..
        services.put(Person.class, new PersonServiceImpl());
        services.put(Employee.class, new EmployeeServiceImpl());
    }

    public <E> E find(long id, Class<E> type) {
        E service = services.get(type);
        if(service == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This API does not provide a service for the specified type.");

        return (E) service.find(id);
    }
}
```

**This lacks type safety.** However, you can implement type safety through:

- Proper type binding: *each entity should share a common type*
- Implementing multi-dispatch via the visitor pattern *(opposed to `instanceof` type checking, or worse: no actual type checking).*

You can now truly encapsulate the services in your API: the client only knows of the entities, not the actual service being used to obtain that entity.

The client would use this as follow:

```
SuperService service = new SuperService();
Person person = service.find(50, Person.class);
```

Comment: This sounds nice. The only issue I can see, unless I'm missing something, is the need to change existing clients to match the new method signature. Now that I think about it (will need an actual confirmation) OP might want to keep the old clients as they were, but in the new ones to use the _smaller API contracts_. If that is so, pehaps we're looking at the solution from the wrong angle. He can keep the existing interface for old clients, and inject the new ones in newly created clients, while the new implementations wrap the old one to just delegate calls for their specific exposed methods.

Comment: This breaks contract of "SuperInterface", but I have to admit it's a nice solution (+1).

Answer (score 1):

In the way you're trying to do it is not possible, for a type implementing/inheriting from different types for which multiple method exist with the same signature, the type that implement/inherit has just one version of the method, whenever the signatures differ only in their return type, there's a compatibility issue that prompt in compile-time.